# I want to download an image in a PWA but it doesn't work on iOS, only in Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I wanted to know if you are familiar with any library that I can use to download images that works on iOS. I have already tried the following libraries, but they don't work: axios, ajax, jquery, RNFetchBlob, html2canvas, file-saver, and dom-to-image.

Currently, my code looks like this. It works on Android, but I can't download the image on iOS.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './Header';
import CopyIcon from './icons/copyIcon';
import ChevronIcon from './icons/chevronIcon';
import { CircleSpinner } from 'react-spinners-kit';
import { sendPdfQR } from '../actions/associatesActions';
import ContentApp from './ContentApp';
import Button from './Common/Button/Button';
import QrIcon from './icons/qrIcon';

const MyQr = ({ history }) => {
  const app = useSelector((state) => state.app);
  const [showQR, setShowQr] = useState(false);
  const [qrUrl, setQrUrl] = useState(null);
  const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);
  const [sendingEmail, setSendingEmail] = useState(false);
  const [emailSent, setEmailSent] = useState(false);
  const [downloading, setDownloading] = useState(false);
  const associate = useSelector((state) => state.associates);
  const userSetup = useSelector((state) => state.associates.salesSetup);
  const jwt = useSelector((state) => state.associates.jwt);

  const onCopy = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(qrUrl);
    setCopied(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCopied(false);
    }, 2000);
  };

  const download = async () => {
    setDownloading(true);
    const qrCodeImageUrl = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=512x512&format=png&data=${qrUrl}`;

    const response = await fetch(qrCodeImageUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'my-qr.png';
    link.click();
    setDownloading(false);
  };

  const sendPdf = () => {
    setSendingEmail(true);
    sendPdfQR(jwt)
      .then((response) => {
        setSendingEmail(false);
        setEmailSent(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setEmailSent(false);
        }, 5000);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setSendingEmail(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userSetup !== null) {
      const subdomain = app.scopeOrganization.organizationNameId;
      setQrUrl(`${app.webURL.replace('www', subdomain)}/?ref=${userSetup.refCode}`);
    }
  }, [userSetup]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header title={''} history={history} />
      <ContentApp header={true}>
        {showQR ? (
          <>
            <div className='card bg-gray-dark mt-5 associate-balance-deposit p-3'>
              <div className='text-center'>
                <img alt='logo' className='show-img' src={app.scopeOrganization.organizationLogo} />
              </div>
              <div className='associate-qr'>
                {qrUrl != null ? (
                  <img
                    alt='QR Code'
                    src={`https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=256x256&format=png&data=${qrUrl}`}
                  />
                ) : (
                  ''
                )}
              </div>
              {qrUrl != null ? (
                <div
                  className='text-gray text-10 text-center qr-copy-icon'
                  onClick={() => onCopy()}
                >
                  {qrUrl} <CopyIcon fillColor={'#C2C2C2'} />
                </div>
              ) : (
                ''
              )}
              {copied && <div className='mt-2 text-13 text-center text-gray'>Copiado</div>}
            </div>
            <div className='card bg-gray-dark mt-3 text-13'>
              <div
                className='col-12 p-2 px-3 border-bottom border-dark'
                onClick={() => onCopy(true)}
              >
                <div className='row'>
                  <div className='col my-auto'>Copiar URL para compartir</div>
                  <div className='col-auto'>
                    <ChevronIcon size={'22px'} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='col-12 p-2 px-3 border-bottom border-dark' onClick={() => sendPdf()}>
                <div className='row'>
                  <div className='col my-auto'>Versión para imprimir</div>
                  <div className='col-auto'>
                    {sendingEmail ? (
                      <CircleSpinner size={22} color='#ffffff' />
                    ) : (
                      <ChevronIcon size={'22px'} />
                    )}
                  </div>
                  {emailSent && (
                    <div className='col-12 p-3 font-weight-300'>
                      Hemos enviado a tu correo electrónico <b>{associate.user.email}</b> un archivo
                      PDF con diferentes formatos para que puedas imprimir este código QR con la
                      mejor calidad posible.
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='col-12 p-2 px-3' onClick={() => download()}>
                <div className='row'>
                  <div className='col my-auto'>Guardar como imagen</div>
                  <div className='col-auto'>
                    {downloading ? (
                      <CircleSpinner size={22} color='#ffffff' />
                    ) : (
                      <ChevronIcon size={'22px'} />
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div
              className='mt-5 pt-5 px-5 mx-5 text-18 font-weight-bold text-center'
              style={{ color: '#DBDBDB' }}
            >
              <div>
                <QrIcon color='#503ec4' size='39px' />
              </div>
              <div className='mt-3'>Empieza a vender con código QR</div>
            </div>
            <div className='text-center text-secondary mt-3 px-2' style={{ fontSize: '14px' }}>
              <p>
                Tus clientes lo escanean desde su dispositivo y cuando compran, recibes una comisión
                al instante.
              </p>
              <p>
                Exhibe tu código QR para que puedan comprar boletos desde el sitio oficial y ganar
                comisiones de esas ventas.
              </p>
              <p>
                Puedes mostrarles el código QR directamente desde tu dispositivo o generar
                impresiones y distribuirlas por diferentes lugares para captar más ventas.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className='mt-5 pt-5 text-center'>
              <Button text={'Continuar'} size='large' onClick={() => setShowQr(true)} />
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </ContentApp>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyQr;
```

I would like to modify the code to make it work on both Android and iOS platforms.